# Which Servlet Listener does not need to be configured in web.xml?

Tags: servlets, listener, web.xml, configure

I am talking about pure servlet application (assuming no framework is used). Which Servlet Listener does not need to be configured in web.xml? and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpSessionBindingListener are not registered in the DD.. It just happens automatically..
The HttpSession object should take care of this itself.. The HttpSession implementation should work something like the following:

```
public void SetAttribute( String name, Object value ) {  
   if( value instanceof HttpSessionBindingListener ) {  
   // Build HttpSessionBindingEvent  
   value.valueBound( event );  
 }  

  // Do the rest  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The listener `HttpSessionActivationListener` is not needed to be configured in `web.xml`. Although I do not know the exact reason why it need not be configured, I think it deals with session activation and passive events when the session is being migrated from one JVM to another JVM.

You can refer javadoc for [HttpSessionActivationListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionActivationListener.html)

Comment: Somewhere during a google search I found one reason "java.lang.HttpSessionActivationListener like java.lang.HttpSessionBindingListener is to be implemented by an attribute class. Such a class need not be instantiated by the container. So it must not be configured in the DD." Could you please elaborate it.